# anythingSlider onShowPause

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I have two sliders. Necessary that they stopped at the same time, when hover on some of them.
My code:

```
    $('.slider').anythingSlider({   
                autoPlay            : true,
                delay               : 1000,  
                autoPlayLocked      : true,
                infiniteSlides      : false,
                stopAtEnd           : false,

                onShowUnpause : function(e, slider){
                    $('.slider').each(function() {
                        $(this).data('AnythingSlider').startStop();
                    });

                },

                onShowPause: function(e, slider){
                    $('.slider').each(function() {
                        $(this).data('AnythingSlider').startStop(false);
                    });

                }
            });
```

But this not working

Comment: not sure what you want. can you explain little more?

Comment: I want to synchronize two sliders. They slides on autoplay. But if hover on  some of them - must stop both (pauseOnHover: true).

Answer (score 0):

When using the `startStop()` function, it actually completely stops the slideshow, so the `onShowUnpause` function will never fire. Try this instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/9752/)):

```
$('.slider').anythingSlider({
    autoPlay: true,
    delay: 1000,
    resumeDelay : 1000,
    autoPlayLocked: true,
    infiniteSlides: false,
    stopAtEnd: false,
    onShowPause: function (e, slider) {
        $('.slider').each(function () {
            $(this).data('AnythingSlider').startStop();
        });
    }
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.slider').each(function(){
        $(this).data('AnythingSlider').startStop(true);
    });
});
```